# how to create cck field in drupal 6

Tags: drupal-6, field, cck

I  created a content type which name is product. the product should have one or more features. each feature has two parts: one is feature title, the other is feature description.
So what I need is a "feature" field with unlimited number of values. How to create a "feature" field with cck in drupal 6?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you need the feature title and feature description fields tied together, I recommend you upgrade to CCK 3 and use the multigroup field, which will allow a mapping of that type.

Comment: After I upgrade to cck-6.x-3.0-alpha3, there is a module "content multigroup". create a multigroup with unlimited value.

Comment: the question is after I upgrade from cck-6.x-2.9 to cck-6.x-3.0-alpha3, and create a "multigroup", when I try to create a product page, there is an error "warning: array_keys() [function.array-keys]: The first argument should be an array in F:\wamp\www\drupals\sitepro\modules\cck\modules\content_multigroup\content_multigroup.node_form.inc on line 315."

Comment: That would be a question for the module's [issue queue](http://drupal.org/project/issues/cck?categories=All)

Answer (score -1):

Click through the following links:
Administration > Content management > Content Types > the Content type in question > Manage Fields > At the bottom you will see ability to add fields